# Django POST With Using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have one app name register_login and this app manages login and register opeartions. I have a form on localhost:8000/login page and i want that the button redirects to my func in register_login app but i cant do it. I'm new at Django Framework. How can i handle this?

## MAIN URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin
from register_login.views import login, register, test


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^homepage/', include('homepage.urls')),
    url(r'^login/$', login),
    url(r'^register/$', register),
    url(r'^success/$', test),
]
```

## LOGIN PAGE .HTML

```
<form id=registerLogin style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 350px;">
      <header>Login</header>
      <label >Username <span>*</span></label>
      <input id="username"/>
      <label >Password <span>*</span></label>
      <input id="password"/>
      <button id="login">Login</button>
      <h1 style="margin-left: 20px;">Are you not registered?</h1>
      <button id="register">Register</button>
</form>
```

At the end of this html there is my .js file. I didnt forget.

## JAVASCRIPT

```
if (!jQuery) { throw new Error("This page requires jQuery") }


function readInput() {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userName = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    debugger

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/success/",
        data: {'username':username,'password':password, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(json) {
            $('#post-text').val(''); // remove the value from the input
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        },     
    }); 
}

(function ($) {

$("#login").click(function(){
    readInput();
});


})(jQuery);
```

And finally my function. Its in register_login app as i said before

## REGISTER_LOGIN VIEW

```
def test(request):
    embed()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        embed()
    return HttpResponse("hell world")
```

I tried to change url like "/register_login/success/","/register_login/success","/register_login/success/$","/success/","success/" or "/success/$". Nothing works

I need to go that function but it doesnt :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you are logging in via ajax, you can not redirect in your `test` view. What you can do is add a redirect in your ajax success function.  Something like this:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("/some-url/");
```

or

```
// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "/some-url/";
```

Also, you need to fix your javascript code, add preventDefault in the click handler and remove it in the readInput.  You also need to remove the quotes in the data object and make sure you used the correct variables. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    function readInput() {
        var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/success/",
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(json) {
                window.location.replace("/some-url/");
            }
        }); 
    }

    $("#login").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        readInput();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need to my func() with ajax but i cant :(

Comment: @Berkin Do you mean you did not get into the `test` method?

Comment: when i click "login" button, i need to pass username and password variable to my func -its test- to check with my database variables to authenticate. But in my case, i cant pass my json to my function :(

Comment: @Berkin I have updated my answer, please make sure that you have jquery and then check the variables you are using in your javascript.